# Injecting $scope in manually instantiated controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to inject $scope in a controller created using the $controller service.

I'm getting the following error:
**Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- TestController**

It's important to mention that the creation is happening inside a directive's link function.

---

I've written a simple example to show the error.

app.js:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('app', [])

    .controller('TestController', [
        '$scope',
        function($scope) {
            // I want to be able to use 'message' from the directive's template
            // as if the controller was loaded directly using ng-controller
            $scope.message = 'Hello World!';
        }
    ])

    .directive('directive', [
        '$controller',
        function($controller) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                template: '<div>{{ message }}</div>',
                link: function(scope) {
                    // In the actual app the controller is dynamically selected
                    // I'm registering a $watch here that provides me the
                    // name of the controller
                    scope.myController = $controller('TestController');
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
})();
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <title>Testing injection</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div directive></div>

        <script src="angular.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Question: **Why is this happening? Can you explain me the logic behind this behaviour? Any workaround?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Digix's answer, I was able to make it work:

```
var locals = {};
locals.$scope = scope;
$controller('TestController', locals);
```

My assumption is that in this way, instead of creating a new scope, the controller shares the one of the directive.

Comment: You are correct.  $new() creates a new child scope.  The new scope's parent (the directive scope), can't see the child's properties (i.e message).  Using the directive's scope directly means that the controller is adding the message property to the directive scope, so the directive template can use it.

Answer (score -2):

```
var locals = {};
locals.$scope = scope.$new();
$controller('testCtrl', locals);
```

Comment: You should really provide more content to this answer. OP _explicitly_ ask for an explanation.

Comment: This code _for some reason_ fixes the error, but I still can't access the variables in the (just created) $scope. Basically, {{ message }} is showing nothing.